# Grouping By 2 Columns In Pandas Ignoring Order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe in Pandas where there are 2 columns that are almost identical but not quite and hence sometimes I want to group by both columns ignoring the order.

As an example:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'Colour1': ['Red', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Blue'], 'Colour2': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Green'], 'Rating': [4, 5, 7, 8, 2]})
```

```
  Colour1 Colour2  Rating
0     Red     Red       4
1     Red    Blue       5
2    Blue     Red       7
3   Green    Blue       8
4    Blue   Green       2
```

I would like to group by Colour1 and Colour2 whilst ignoring the order and then transforming the Dataframe by taking the mean to produce the following Dataframe:

```
  Colour1 Colour2  Rating  MeanRating
0     Red     Red       4           4
1     Red    Blue       5           6
2    Blue     Red       7           6
3   Green    Blue       8           5
4    Blue   Green       2           5
```

Is there a good way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first sort the column1 and 2 using np.sort then groupby:

```
s = pd.Series(map(tuple,np.sort(mydf[['Colour1','Colour2']],axis=1)),index=mydf.index)
mydf['MeanRating'] = mydf['Rating'].groupby(s).transform('mean')
```

---

```
print(mydf)

  Colour1 Colour2  Rating  MeanRating
0     Red     Red       4           4
1     Red    Blue       5           6
2    Blue     Red       7           6
3   Green    Blue       8           5
4    Blue   Green       2           5
```